# How to reference application settings (key vault references) in Azure Function using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app

I am writing a small program in Powershell which connects to Office 365 to download audit logs, make some changes and then export a CSV to an Azure Data Lake Storage account. To run this process on a schedule, I have created an Azure Function app (timer template) to run the program. To avoid hard-coded credentials, I created an Azure Key Vault to store the credential secrets. I created a managed identity in the Azure Function, created the secrets in Azure Key Vault with the credentials and then created three application settings in Azure Function under "Configuration" with the URL to point at the secrets stored in Azure Key Vault.

[image: Key Vault References under "Configuration" in Azure Function]

The three application settings are called "SecretUsername", "SecretPassword" (to point to the Office 365) and "SecretSAS" (to store the CSV in ADLS).

How do I refer to these variables in my Powershell script? I have tried different variations in my code, but none appear to work. Examples:

- $uSecret = $SecretUsername
- $uSecret = $ENV:SecretUsername
- $uSecret = ENV:SecretUsername
- $uSecret = (Get-ChildItem ENV:SecretUsername).SecretValueText

  ```
   # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
   param($Timer)

   # Get the current universal time in the default string format.
   $currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

   # The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
   if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
       Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
   }

   # Write an information log with the current time.
   Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"

   Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned 
   Set-Item ENV:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"

   $uSecret = (Get-ChildItem ENV:SecretUsername).SecretValueText 
   $pSecret = (Get-ChildItem ENV:SecretPassword).SecretValueText 
   $sasSecret = (Get-ChildItem ENV:SecretSAS).SecretValueText 
   $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pSecret -AsPlainText -Force
   $UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $uSecret, $securePassword

   $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
   Import-PSSession $session

   $startDate=(get-date).AddDays(-10)
   $endDate=(get-date)
   $scriptStart=(get-date)

   $sessionName = (get-date -Format 'u')+'pbiauditlog'

   $aggregateResults = @()
   $i = 0 # Loop counter
   Do { 
       $currentResults = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $enddate -SessionId $sessionName -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 1000 -RecordType PowerBIAudit
       if ($currentResults.Count -gt 0) {
           Write-Host ("Finished {3} search #{1}, {2} records: {0} min" -f [math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $scriptStart).TotalMinutes,4), $i, $currentResults.Count, $user.UserPrincipalName )
           # Accumulate the data.
           $aggregateResults += $currentResults
           # No need to do another query if the # records returned <1000 - should save around 5-10 seconds per user.
           if ($currentResults.Count -lt 1000) {
               $currentResults = @()
           } else {
               $i++
           }
       }
   } Until ($currentResults.Count -eq 0) # End of Session Search Loop.

   $data=@()

   foreach ($auditlogitem in $aggregateResults) {
       $datum = New-Object -TypeName PSObject  
       $d = ConvertFrom-json $auditlogitem.AuditData
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Id -Value $d.Id
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreationTDateTime -Value $d.CreationDate
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreationTime -Value $d.CreationTime
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordType -Value $d.RecordType
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operation -Value $d.Operation
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OrganizationId -Value $d.OrganizationId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserType -Value $d.UserType
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserKey -Value $d.UserKey
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Workload -Value $d.Workload        
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserId -Value $d.UserId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ClientIPAddress -Value $d.ClientIPAddress
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserAgent -Value $d.UserAgent
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Activity -Value $d.Activity
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ItemName -Value $d.ItemName
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WorkSpaceName -Value $d.WorkSpaceName
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DashboardName -Value $d.DashboardName
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DatasetName -Value $d.DatasetName
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ReportName -Value $d.ReportName
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WorkspaceId -Value $d.WorkspaceId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectId -Value $d.ObjectId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DashboardId -Value $d.DashboardId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DatasetId -Value $d.DatasetId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ReportId -Value $d.ReportId
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OrgAppPermission -Value $d.OrgAppPermission

       # Option to include the below JSON column however for large amounts of data it may be difficult for PBI to parse
       $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Datasets -Value (ConvertTo-Json $d.Datasets)

       # Below is a simple PowerShell statement to grab one of the entries and place in the DatasetName if any exist
       foreach ($dataset in $d.datasets) {
           $datum.DatasetName = $dataset.DatasetName
           $datum.DatasetId = $dataset.DatasetId
       }
       $data+=$datum
   }

   $dateTimestring = $startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd") + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "HHmm")
   $fileName = ($dateTimestring + ".csv")
   Write-Host ("Writing to file {0}" -f $fileName) 
   $filePath = "$Env:temp/" + $fileName
   $data | Export-csv -Path $filePath

   Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential
   Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Audit" -status
   $Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "auditingstorage" -StorageAccountKey $sasSecret
   Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Force -Context $Context -Container "auditlogs" -File $filePath -Blob $filename 

   Remove-PSSession -Id $Session.Id
  ```

How do I reference the application settings in Azure Function so that I can use the stored secrets in my program?

Please assist! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the app settings, keyvault or not, you must retrieve it trhough : `$env:APPSETTING_YourSettingName`

Thus, for your keyvault referenced secret, you would access it through the following variables.

```
$env:APPSETTING_SecretUserName
$env:APPSETTING_SecretPassword
$env:APPSETTING_SecretSAS
```

And if ever you need to produce a list of them.

```
Get-ChildItem env:APPSETTING_*
```

Note, the values returned will plain text unencrypted string.
Therefore, in your code, this:

```
 $uSecret = (Get-ChildItem ENV:SecretUsername).SecretValueText
```

becomes that:

```
 $uSecret = $env:APPSETTING_SecretUserName
```

**Additional note**

Since it was pointed out in the comments, I'll mention it.
I am not advocating the use of clear text secret in app settings at all.

App settings should be a keyvault referene for any sensitive data.
I am simply stating that it can be retrieved within the function at runtime as clear-text through the `$env:APPSETTING_YourSettingName` variable.

Example:
AppSetting name : MySecretUser
AppSetting value: @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
Actual secret value (In the keyvault) : I_AM_Secret

At runtime, getting the value of `$env:APPSETTING_MySecretUser` will return  a String Object with the value **I_AM_Secret**

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I believe you misunderstood my answer. I do not recommend OP to put his secret as clear text (This should never be the case for any confidential data). Secrets should be referenced in the AppSettings through a keyvault reference. This is already what OP is doing. I am simply stating that whenever you add a keyvault reference, such as `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)`, it is available for use within your function through the `$env:AppSetting_SecretName` variable.

Comment: `$env:AppSetting_SecretName` do contain the clear text value of the keyvault reference contained in the app setting.

Comment: Thank you @sagepourpre `$env:APPSETTING_` works great! All this time, I thought "APPSETTING" was to be substituted with the name of the variable and I hadn't realised that it was a keyword. 

I have also raised a separate but related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751380/accessing-key-vault-secrets-securely) which I need help with. If you have a moment please take a look! Thanks